# EasyMock: How to get attributes from a private void method

Tags: java, easymock

```
public class A { 
 public void m1(obj o){
   m2(params);
 }
 private void m2(params){
   String s;
   //some actions with String S
   m3(s);
 }
 private void m3(String s){
   m4(s);
 }
 private void m4(String s){

   //some actions with s
 }
}
```

So somehow I need to get String s that m4() recieves as a parameter, I need to catch that parameter so I can put a different obj in m1() and it will make a different string in m2() and so I can comapare them using EasyMock or maybe there is a way to do this not using EasyMock. Im stuck here and I have no idea how to do this.

```
a.m1(obj);
```

This is the usage of my class, so it calls a chain reaction that is closed by privates. I hope i did a good job explaining my problem.

Comment: There is no way to get String s tested if this is local private method's variable. You need some dependency injection technique to make it testable. You can try to pass some parameters hashmap down to your m2 through your constructor and then verify it's content in your test.

Comment: As Luke said, you need a different approach if you're dealing with local variables.  Moreover, if you need to mock private methods, you might check out PowerMock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test this method, you may [consider making it public/protected/package local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586/1851024). Then you'll be able to mock or overload it in a subclass you are to test.